# How to resolve git conflict to overwrite my changes?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, conflict

How can I pull changes from the branch and overwrite anything I have if it is conflicted? My local copy is not important (!) - only on the branch we have important changes.

[image]

I'm new to Git.

Comment: Please don't post text as images, it makes it difficult to copy and search

Comment: @ConnorStoop sure, thanks

Comment: `git reset --hard`

Comment: `error: Merging is not possible because you have unmergd files.` You started a merge but never finished it. Note that `git pull` *runs* `git merge` (or, if you choose, `git rebase` instead). Note: don't just switch to rebase either; rebase does merges too. Pick merge or rebase *on purpose*, to achieve the desired goal, and read up on resolving conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your local changes are not important, abort the merge with `git merge --abort`
Revert your changes with `git restore --staged .` and `git restore .`
Then try to merge again

Comment: It almost worked, but after git pull it again shows: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge. Please move or remove them before you merge.

Comment: I use git pull to merge

Comment: Can I somehow remove all untracked files?

Comment: I add them using ' git add . ', now i see new error when I try to pull: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge. Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.

Comment: Should I commit them? I just want to overwrite them.

Comment: I used git stash, then git pull, and then git stash clear, it worked.

Comment: @Rumata good to hear it worked, you could also clear untracked files with `git clean fd`